# Commercial Software for Interactive Machine Learning and Annotation in NLP

Tags: nlp, active-learning

We are evaluating make or buy for a tool for interactive machine learning on legal text. With little labeling effort, it should enable for (ml layman) domain experts to build classifiers on a GUI.

Regarding commercial solutions, a came across prodi.gy of explosion AI. 
It looks great and their spacy lib is awesome too.

What are competing commercial solutions in the (inter)active ML / semisupervised space, ideally geared towards NLP (legal would be a +)? Also looking into startups.

Thanks in advance.